# CSS ouput php echo without tables

Tags: php, html, css

Is there a way to get a excel spreadsheet type of format with the things I echo out in PHP, without using a table?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['user'] . " " . $row['email'] . " " . $row['age'] . " " . $row['image'] . " " . $row['created_at'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: while tables for page layout are frowned upon, this looks like a good semantic use of tables to me

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `<table>`?

Comment: I'd love to use <table> it's just that the client doesn't want me to. That's why I'm sort of stuck on this matter...

Comment: You should recommend that your client use tables, unless this isn't some kind of tabular data, in my opinion. This of course doesn't change the problem, but just as a note - keep clients informed of good web practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `div`. set the `width` as you want.

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("test",mysql_connect("localhost","root",""));

$result = mysql_query("select * from test");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $counter++;
?>
<div style="clear:left; float:left; width:604px;<?php echo $counter == $count ? "border-bottom:1px solid black;" : ""; ?>">
    <div style="float:left; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; width:200px;"><?php echo $row['fullname'] ?></div>
    <div style="float:left; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; width:200px;"><?php echo $row['email'] ?></div>
    <div style="float:left; border-right:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black; width:200px;"><?php echo $row['password'] ?></div>
</div>
<?php   
}
?>
```

This will give you output like this,
[image]

Comment: I think this script just might be what he's looking for? Will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure ! if you get any problem you may ask me anytime ! :)

Comment: @yorzakis - is this what your client was looking for?? any doubts??

Comment: I'm not sure but it sure looks like what he's asking for. I'm going to find out tomorrow. Will let you know. Thank you again!

Comment: sorry, got caught up in the project. Yes that is what the client was asking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use blue print CSS for showing the grid.

Please look at the `http://www.blueprintcss.org/`.

Comment: Checked it out, but even on their sample page they are using tables. And I don't want to use another program to do my output, I'd rather learn how to do it myself. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS to the HTML elements with PHP embedded in your code.

Example:

```
<table class="style_1">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
    <tr class="style_2">
        <td class="style3"> <? $row['user'] ?></td>
        <td class="style3"> <? $row['email'] ?></td>
        <td class="style3"> <? $row['age'] ?></td>
     </tr>

 <? } ?>
```

Comment: well he did say without using a table

Comment: lol yeah sorry, I have a project I'm working on and my client said no tables what so ever!! So, I wanted to see if it's even possible. Thank you.

Comment: tell the client to leave the web work to you, that's what you are paid for then chose the appropriate technology. Assume he meant html tables, and not something else.

Comment: no he does mean html tables, guess the guy has something against tables. but I do try to give what my cleints ask and pay for, with-in reason...